# Where can I find a list of online Esperanto Magazines?

Tags: culture

I know [Monato](https://www.monato.be/); are there any other online magazines? And if so, where can I find an (exhaustive) list?

Comment: This site has a list of Esperanto material for a variety of categories: http://www.liberalibrejo.com/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not an exhaustive list, but there is [a list of magazines you can subscribe to through UEA](http://katalogo.uea.org/index.php?st=abonoj).

A subset of those are also available [through the Esperanto Association of Britain](http://esperanto.org.uk/eab/bookcat.htm#sec8), as well as [through Esperanto-USA](http://esperanto-usa.org/retbutiko/index.php?main_page=index&cPath=1002_1003).

Answer (score 5):

For french speaker, the association Espéranto-France put his revue on the net :
http://esperanto-france.org/le-monde-de-l-esperanto

You'll found some article in esperanto and others in french.

Answer (score 4):

Monato is a paper magazine. There are many online 
magazines, not so easy to find.

La Esperanto-centro: EVENTOJ. 
In this web page you can find several publications.

http://eventoj.hu/

RET-INFO – Retpoŝta Esperanto-novaĵservo! 
(They will send it to you)

EVENTOJ - plena arkivo, 
all the magazines published between 1992 and 2002.

Juna Amiko – arkivo de 40 jaroj, all the magazines between 1974 and 2014. The paper version of this magazine is still being published. They will keep adding them ... 2 years late.

Internacia Scienca Asocio Esperantista, ISAE - kaj Scienca Revuo. Some articles from the paper science magazine.

Faka literaturo en Esperanto, S.T.E.B, huge collection of science books and articles, by subject.

La Karavelo, you can download 27 issues:

http://joaojosesantos.net/revuoj_eo.html

Comment: MONATO is not just a paper magazine. It exists also as PDF, as ePub for mobile phones and all the articles appear online even before the paper magazine is sent to the readers. For reference you can check http://www.monato.net/pdf/

Answer (score 4):

Here you have a list of the most probably known with a little description, although in Spanish: [revistas en esperanto](http://enricbaltasar.com/revistas-esperanto/).

Also, it is linked a [catalogue of Catalan Esperanto Association](http://victorsole.com/esperanto/perado/) in this article.

Answer (score 4):

A very good one is "La ondo de Esperanto" - http://esperanto-ondo.ru/Libroj/Libroj.php
Some free samples of the best well known you can find here:http://dvd.ikso.net/pagxo/eo/revuo.html

Answer (score 4):

There is also a quite new magazine made by membres of the Telegram "Esperantujo" group, named Umujo :
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0BwWhyDWcKt2VdWw5aTZ1b0Y4dGc